# ASP.NET Core routing multiple PUT verbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing

I've been trying to create an API in .NET Core 6 with Swagger enabled, and two methods using `Put` verb. I'm getting an error saying both routes match the same params.

```cs
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody] Data data) {};

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult ToggleActivate(int id, bool active) {};
```

Pretending the first one would reply to `/SampleController/5` and allow a regular update, and the second one to `/SampleController/5/ToggleActivate`

I've seen almost in every post about it that it should be decorated with a Route attribute but have tried some variants and none seem to work. And get the error:

> Conflicting method/path combination "PUT api/SampleController/{id}"

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Then make the route for the second one something like this: `[HttpPut("{id}/ToggleActivate")]`

Comment: That seems to work, the only thing is swagger doesn't show ID as parameter :(

Comment: I had an OperationFilter beeing too greedy with that parameter, your suggestion actually solves this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can add route to your action verbs i.e.  **[HttpPut("{id}/Update")]**, **[HttpPut("{id}/ToggleActivate")]**